# Espresso selection of child view not working which have same id

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am using espresso for automating testing in that I am struck at one issue where I am not able to get View of child from it's parent.

Inside main_activity.xml and sample.xml

```
<include 
   android:id="@+id/main"
   android:layout="@layout/sample" />
```

Here is an example of what is within the @layout/sample

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

above main layout used two times as given

while running test I am getting an error

```
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException:  multiple views in the hierarchy.
    Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.
```

I also tried with below code but it gives me same result.

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.button1), withParent(withId(R.id.include_one))))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
                .perform(click());
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: have edited the answer please have a look

Comment: This is not the exception you had previously, is it? Also, this is not the whole stacktrace.

Comment: it's too long i just give it to you has a reference

Comment: Previously you had `multiple views matching`, right?

Comment: do you have any pointer whats wrong here? can you please help me

Comment: sorry that was the actual error.That occure because my I am using same id inside multiple layout. now I want to click on it while doing these i m getting "multiple views matching"